# Export textanalysis to pdf

Tags: export, text

In the helpfile there is a nice axample of text analysis (example/LexicalAnalysis)

```
Text[Row[With[{data = 
     ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}, "Words"]}, 
   Table[Style[data[[i]], 
     10 N[Log[Count[Take[data, i], data[[i]]]]]], {i, Length[data]}]],
   " "]]
```

The result of this scripts is[image]

When I export this output as a pdf file, the result is a empty document. On the internet I found a suggestion to export first to the formmat 'eps' and then to 'pdf'. In my case I created onley the last page. Anybody a suggestion to export this analysis (in the way it's formatted) to somebody else who has no mathematica on his computer.

Answer (score 6):

I checked the exported EPS from Mathematica on Windows 8.1. The whole contents are all included in the EPS file, but the page size / bounding box is quite unusual. So I guess it's possible the PS-to-PDF converter you used did not respect that page size, thus some contents are cropped. I found two ways working here:

1. Using MMA's converter, *i.e.*

   ```
   Export["xx.pdf", 
          ImportString[ExportString[testText, "EPS"], "EPS"]
         ]
   ```

   MMA's PDF converter seems respect the page size (at least on my machine), so this will work. But it can be unstable once the `testText` getting large/complex.
2. Exporting to EPS, then using third-party tools (like ps2pdf) to convert it to PDF. In this way, you can [specify the page size in the tool manually](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Use.htm#Paper_size).

In case you want to assign a page size at the very beginning, I found using `Pane` with fixed size is a handy trick. *e.g.*

```
Export["xxx.eps",
       Pane[exampleText, {500, 200}, ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"]
      ]
```

Then in the console run

```
ps2pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=500 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=200 xxx.eps xxx.pdf
```

The result will look somehow similar to `exampleText` in MMA's FrontEnd:

[image: generated pdf]

Finally there are some issues worth notice, e.g. EPS does not support transparency, etc. I would suggest [searching the site for more details](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=EPS%20PDF%20is%3aanswer).

Comment: This works on Macs, too. Annoyingly, the `ImportString` trick doesn't work with `"PDF"` in this example, so `"EPS"` does indeed seem to be unavoidable.

Comment: @Jens I think MMA's PDF converter is too slow and the result files are too large, and it always exist with a corrupted pdf (for this issue maybe I should try again when I have sufficient RAM). I would actually rather set up a special notebook then using whatever pdf virtual printer I have.

Answer (score 1):

If in the notebook you Save Selection as a .PNG, it seems to work fine. the PDF (when viewed with Acrobat Pro) is NOT empty, but has a bunch of empty squares where letters ought to be - I don't know enough about the vagaries of PDF to interpret this.

Comment: The squares probably mean the font is unavailable to Acrobat.